# Отловить ошибку в Laraval 5.7 и SftpAdapter

Tags: php, laravel, файловая-система

Есть код для подключения по sftp:

```
    use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
    use League\Flysystem\Sftp\SftpAdapter;

    public function test(Request $request)
    {

    $adapter = new SftpAdapter([
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => '**.**.**.**',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
    ]);

    $filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
    $response = $filesystem->put('text.txt', 'test test test');

    }
```

Если host недоступен или неверный пароль, приходит сообщение об ошибке. Каким образом ее можно обработать? Пытался

```
    if ($filesystem->put('text.txt', 'test test test')) {
        return 'true';
    }
    else {
        return 'false';
    }
```

Но это не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
$filesystem->put('text.txt', 'test test test');
{
catch (\Exception $e)
{
dd($e);
}
```

такого типа попробуй и смотри не забывай логи в storage/logs